# Terraform create map/dict from TG route table and TG attachment vpns to reference in resource aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table_association

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Adding a Python like psuedo code for explaining what I want to achieve via Terraform.

I have 6 transit gateway route tables, 10 transit gateway VPN attachments
I need this for tansit gateway route table association and propagation

Trying to create a **local** "map/dict" that can be referenced in the resource function aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table_association
The resource function needs transit_gateway_attachment_id and transit_gateway_route_table_id

```
tg_rt = [
  {
    "name" = "A"
    "tg_rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-aa"
  },
  {
    "name" = "B"
    "tg_rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-bb"
  },
  {
    "name" = "C"
    "tg_rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-cc"
  },
  {
    "name" = "D"
    "tg_rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-dd"
  },
  {
    "name" = "E"
    "tg_rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-ee"
  },
{
    "name" = "F"
    "tg_rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-ff"
  },
]
tga_vpn = [
  {
    "name" = "1"
    "tga_id" = "tgw-attach-11"
  },
  {
    "name" = "2"
    "tga_id" = "tgw-attach-22"
  },
  {
    "name" = "3"
    "tga_id" = "tgw-attach-33"
  },
  {
    "name" = "4"
    "tga_id" = "tgw-attach-44"
  },
  {
    "name" = "5"
    "tga_id" = "tgw-attach-55"
  },
  {
    "name" = "6"
    "tga_id" = "tgw-attach-66"
  },
  {
    "name" = "7"
    "tga_id" = "tgw-attach-77"
  },
  {
    "name" = "8"
    "tga_id" = "tgw-attach-88"
  },
]
```

```
  for tgw_rt in tgw_rts:  # list of dicts with id and name 
    for tga_vpn in tga_vpns: # # list of dict with id and name 
      if tgw_rt.name == "PROD" and tga_vpn.name in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
        rt_id = tgw_rt.id
        vpn_attachment_id = tga_vpn.id
      elif tgw_rt.name == "DEV" and tga_vpn.name in [5, 6, 7, 8]:
        rt_id = tgw_rt.id
        vpn_attachment_id = tga_vpn.id
      elif tgw_rt.name == "STAGING" and tga_vpn.name in [9, 10, 11, 12]:
        rt_id = tgw_rt.id
        vpn_attachment_id = tga_vpn.id
```

```
resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table_association" "TGW-RT-VPN-ASSOCIATION" {
  
  for_each = {
    for tg_vpn_attach, tg_vpn_attach_details in local.above_map : tg_vpn_attach => tg_vpn_attach_details
  }
  transit_gateway_route_table_id      = each.rt_id # for reference
  transit_gateway_attachment_id     = each.vpn_attachment_id # for reference 
}
```

Again I have deployed a TGW with half dozen route tables/routes with several VPC and VPN attachment types and looking to create the correct associations/propagations according to the logic format above.

Let me know if there are any questions and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: The best answer will be like before. Split it into multiple resources. Why not use the same approach as suggested before?

Comment: @Marcin
There are many route tables 6 of them and there will be statement for vpc association, vpc propagation and vpn association and vpn propagation.

Comment: @Marcin

That would make it 24 resource statements, which is why I was trying to create a map with associations, so that there will be 4 statements vpc association, vpc propagation and vpn association and vpn propagation
Also, the routes were created from the same resource in a loop, so I cannot have two for_each (vpn attachment ids, and route table ids)  in the resource aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table_association correct ?

Comment: By the way. I noticed that all your previous answers got answers. On one you even write "This helped thank you so much. Appreciate it!!", yet no answer was accepted. Accepting helpful answers is a good practice and helps other readers in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no `[9, 10, 11, 12]` in your `tga_vpn`, so I will just focus on `prod` and `dev`.

You should be able to construct your data structure, assuming that I understand correctly your desired outcome, as follows:

```
variable "tg_rt" {

  default = [
    {
      "name" = "A"
      "tg_rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-aa"
    },
    {
      "name" = "B"
      "tg_rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-bb"
    },
    {
      "name" = "C"
      "tg_rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-cc"
    },
    {
      "name" = "D"
      "tg_rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-dd"
    },
    {
      "name" = "E"
      "tg_rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-ee"
    },
  {
      "name" = "F"
      "tg_rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-ff"
    },
  ]

}
variable "tga_vpn" {

  default =  [
    {
      "name" = "1"
      "tga_id" = "tgw-attach-11"
    },
    {
      "name" = "2"
      "tga_id" = "tgw-attach-22"
    },
    {
      "name" = "3"
      "tga_id" = "tgw-attach-33"
    },
    {
      "name" = "4"
      "tga_id" = "tgw-attach-44"
    },
    {
      "name" = "5"
      "tga_id" = "tgw-attach-55"
    },
    {
      "name" = "6"
      "tga_id" = "tgw-attach-66"
    },
    {
      "name" = "7"
      "tga_id" = "tgw-attach-77"
    },
    {
      "name" = "8"
      "tga_id" = "tgw-attach-88"
    },
  ]  
}

locals {

  prod = merge(flatten([ for idx1, tgw_rt in var.tg_rt:
           {
              for idx2, tga_vpn in var.tga_vpn:
               "${tgw_rt.tg_rt_id}-${ tga_vpn.tga_id}" => 
                      { rt_id = tgw_rt.tg_rt_id
                        vpn_attachment_id = tga_vpn.tga_id
                      } if contains(["1", "2", "3", "4"], tga_vpn.name)
                         
            }    
      ])...)
      
   dev = merge(flatten([ for idx1, tgw_rt in var.tg_rt:
           {
              for idx2, tga_vpn in var.tga_vpn:
               "${tgw_rt.tg_rt_id}-${ tga_vpn.tga_id}" => 
                      { rt_id = tgw_rt.tg_rt_id
                        vpn_attachment_id = tga_vpn.tga_id
                      } if contains(["5", "6", "7", "8"], tga_vpn.name)
                         
            }    
      ])...) 
      
   prod_dev_map = {
     prod = local.prod
     dev  = local.dev
   }
       
}

output "prod" {
  value = local.prod_dev_map
}
```

This will result in `prod_dev_map` being:

```
{
  "dev" = {
    "tgw-rtb-aa-tgw-attach-55" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-aa"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-55"
    }
    "tgw-rtb-aa-tgw-attach-66" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-aa"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-66"
    }
    "tgw-rtb-aa-tgw-attach-77" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-aa"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-77"
    }
    "tgw-rtb-aa-tgw-attach-88" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-aa"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-88"
    }
    "tgw-rtb-bb-tgw-attach-55" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-bb"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-55"
    }
    "tgw-rtb-bb-tgw-attach-66" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-bb"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-66"
    }
    "tgw-rtb-bb-tgw-attach-77" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-bb"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-77"
    }
    "tgw-rtb-bb-tgw-attach-88" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-bb"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-88"
    }
    "tgw-rtb-cc-tgw-attach-55" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-cc"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-55"
    }
    "tgw-rtb-cc-tgw-attach-66" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-cc"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-66"
    }
    "tgw-rtb-cc-tgw-attach-77" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-cc"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-77"
    }
    "tgw-rtb-cc-tgw-attach-88" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-cc"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-88"
    }
    "tgw-rtb-dd-tgw-attach-55" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-dd"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-55"
    }
    "tgw-rtb-dd-tgw-attach-66" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-dd"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-66"
    }
    "tgw-rtb-dd-tgw-attach-77" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-dd"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-77"
    }
    "tgw-rtb-dd-tgw-attach-88" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-dd"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-88"
    }
    "tgw-rtb-ee-tgw-attach-55" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-ee"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-55"
    }
    "tgw-rtb-ee-tgw-attach-66" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-ee"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-66"
    }
    "tgw-rtb-ee-tgw-attach-77" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-ee"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-77"
    }
    "tgw-rtb-ee-tgw-attach-88" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-ee"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-88"
    }
    "tgw-rtb-ff-tgw-attach-55" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-ff"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-55"
    }
    "tgw-rtb-ff-tgw-attach-66" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-ff"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-66"
    }
    "tgw-rtb-ff-tgw-attach-77" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-ff"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-77"
    }
    "tgw-rtb-ff-tgw-attach-88" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-ff"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-88"
    }
  }
  "prod" = {
    "tgw-rtb-aa-tgw-attach-11" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-aa"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-11"
    }
    "tgw-rtb-aa-tgw-attach-22" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-aa"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-22"
    }
    "tgw-rtb-aa-tgw-attach-33" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-aa"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-33"
    }
    "tgw-rtb-aa-tgw-attach-44" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-aa"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-44"
    }
    "tgw-rtb-bb-tgw-attach-11" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-bb"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-11"
    }
    "tgw-rtb-bb-tgw-attach-22" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-bb"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-22"
    }
    "tgw-rtb-bb-tgw-attach-33" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-bb"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-33"
    }
    "tgw-rtb-bb-tgw-attach-44" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-bb"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-44"
    }
    "tgw-rtb-cc-tgw-attach-11" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-cc"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-11"
    }
    "tgw-rtb-cc-tgw-attach-22" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-cc"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-22"
    }
    "tgw-rtb-cc-tgw-attach-33" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-cc"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-33"
    }
    "tgw-rtb-cc-tgw-attach-44" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-cc"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-44"
    }
    "tgw-rtb-dd-tgw-attach-11" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-dd"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-11"
    }
    "tgw-rtb-dd-tgw-attach-22" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-dd"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-22"
    }
    "tgw-rtb-dd-tgw-attach-33" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-dd"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-33"
    }
    "tgw-rtb-dd-tgw-attach-44" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-dd"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-44"
    }
    "tgw-rtb-ee-tgw-attach-11" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-ee"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-11"
    }
    "tgw-rtb-ee-tgw-attach-22" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-ee"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-22"
    }
    "tgw-rtb-ee-tgw-attach-33" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-ee"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-33"
    }
    "tgw-rtb-ee-tgw-attach-44" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-ee"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-44"
    }
    "tgw-rtb-ff-tgw-attach-11" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-ff"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-11"
    }
    "tgw-rtb-ff-tgw-attach-22" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-ff"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-22"
    }
    "tgw-rtb-ff-tgw-attach-33" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-ff"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-33"
    }
    "tgw-rtb-ff-tgw-attach-44" = {
      "rt_id" = "tgw-rtb-ff"
      "vpn_attachment_id" = "tgw-attach-44"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is great @Marcin. 

My only question is can this be merged to one dict ? 

The reason I say that is there are at least 6 envs (like Prod/Dev/Stage) and might grow too. 


If I were to have separate dicts calling it in the resource function would mean 12 statements. 6 resource statements for associations and 6 for propagation. 

I fnot this is good. It is better than 24.

Comment: @VinitaShah Yes, you can merge them. Check updated answer. This will work as long as your combinations of tga_vpn and tga_vpn do not overlap between different environments.

Comment: thank you @Marcin there is an overlap in propagations (not shown in my example pseudo code ) :facepalm:
Can you also please paste your previous answer

Comment: @VinitaShah Hi. I updated the answer again. If its helpful, please accept it. Also if you have future issues, maybe new question would be better with new details and error messages.

Comment: @VinitaShah It is working. `prod` has only combinations of `tgw-attach-11 to tgw-attach-44`, and `dev` has `tgw-attach-55 to tgw-attach-88`. There is no overlap between dev and prod in terms of `tgw-attach`.

Comment: It nearly works @Marcin 
The problem is prod and dev consists of both prod and dev route tables

Comment: @VinitaShah I don't know what do you mean. In your questions, you have some conditions like `tgw_rt.name == "PROD"`, but your variable `tg_rt` does not have any name with PROD. If you add this condiotions, your outcome will be empty.

Comment: Nevermind I had a bad code. It works. THANK YOU so much !!

Comment: @VinitaShah No problem. Glad it worked out:-)